# Cannot install Typescript " The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.25 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!"

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I try to install Typescript to compile Angular2 app but I get the following error " The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.25 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!"

Comment: Is there actually a problem running the software, or is that NPM being fussy? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: I#m very new to Angular2 and I try to follow the tutorial in "ng-book2" and the first thing to do is to install node.js what I've done, then install typescript to compile the ts files. but I keep getting the following errors: 139 error node v4.6.0
140 error npm  v2.15.9
141 error code EPEERINVALID
142 error peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.25 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
142 error peerinvalid Peer html-webpack-plugin@2.22.0 wants webpack@*
142 error peerinvalid Peer karma-webpack@1.8.0 wants webpack@^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta
142 error peerinv

Comment: Again, is there actually a problem running the software? NPM can be very verbose, and you may find that everything runs fine despite warnings and even errors.

Comment: Have you looked into angular-cli? Also when you install typescript are you installing it globally or in the local application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems as you. However I was trying to install the angular-cli, so my fix may or may not work for you. After much mucking around, I found that installing portfinder seems to solve the problems. I ran:

```
npm install portfinder
```

Then I ran the cli install and it worked. See if that works for you.
Oh, and you need to be running atleast node 4.x and npm 3.x